# jQuery(element).offset().top temporarily inaccurate when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fire events once an element comes into view, for a few different elements at different places in the page.  I am using a utility function from another StackExchange answer to handle determining when Element A or Element B comes into view, specifically using jQuery(element).offset().top to determine when the element is in view.  In this example, let's assume Element A is higher in the page, so it should be seen first, followed down the page by Element B.

When Element A comes into view, the code for Element A fires as expected, but Element B also fires, even though it's ~1000 down the screen and completely out of view. jQuery(element).offset().top for Element B returns a number ~1400 less than the actual placement of Element B for a few seconds after Element A triggers, it then corrects itself after scrolling a bit further

I've tried tracking the variables in the Console and using both jQuery(element).offset().top; and jQuery(element).position().top; but have had no luck.

The utility function I am using to do so is this:

```
function Utils() {
  }
Utils.prototype = {
    constructor: Utils,
    isElementInView: function (element, fullyInView) {
        var pageTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        var pageBottom = pageTop + jQuery(window).height();
        var elementTop = jQuery(element).offset().top;
        var elementBottom = elementTop + jQuery(element).height();

        if (fullyInView === true) {
            return ((pageTop < elementTop) && (pageBottom > elementBottom));
        } else {
            return ((elementBottom >= pageTop) && (elementTop <= pageBottom));
        }
    }
};
var Utils = new Utils();
```

I am calling the function like so:

```
var xyz = Utils.isElementInView(ElementA, false);
              if(xyz) { then do stuff }
var zzz = Utils.isElementInView(ElementB, false);
              if(zzz) { then do stuff }
```

When I track the elementTop for Elements 1/2 and PageBottom in the console I am seeing this happen:

```
(index):1237 elementTop : 4499 - Element 1 Top
(index):1235 PageBottom: 4496
(index):1237 elementTop : 5454 - Element 2 Top
(index):1235 PageBottom: 4499
(index):1237 elementTop : 4499 - Element 1 Top
(index):1302 Event Firing for Element 1
(index):1235 PageBottom: 4499
(index):1237 elementTop : 4148 - Element 2 Top
(index):1310 Event Firing for Element 2
(index):1235 PageBottom: 4500
(index):1237 elementTop : 4149 - Element 2 Top
(index):1310 Event Firing for Element 2
(index):1235 PageBottom: 4501
(index):1237 elementTop : 5454 - Element 2 Top
```

When I get around when Element 1 comes into view (4499), the top returned for Element 2 is 5454.  Immediately when Element 1 comes into view, Element 2 also fires because the top returned for Element 2 becomes 4148.  The top for Element 2 corrects itself after a bit of scrolling and is back to 5454.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Hi @Nick, could you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding.  Unfortunately, it's a WordPress site, so I can't copy and paste code other than what I've given.  I tried to repro on my own without WordPress and I can't seem to repro it locally.  So maybe it's something to do with WordPress.

Comment: Well, I made an example that I think is similar to what you're describing https://jsfiddle.net/1z6fj7ph/ but it looks like it's working as expected.

Comment: I think it's a problem with WordPress, I ended up using a workaround to skip checking whether the other elements are visible until after the current element is not.  Hopefully if someone else finds this question, this will be helpful for them.